# How to concatenate different properties into one column

Tags: angular, typescript, concatenation

on TypeScript i'm trying to concatenate two properties into one column, is it possible?

For example, i have "Dog" and "Cat" properties and i want to show both into a single column named "Animals" in the matTable.

So in a single cell of the column "Animals" i'm going to see "Dog, Cat".

Here i made two separate columns but I'm not sure how to see more than one property in the same cell:

```
configureColumns() {
    this.columns = [
      {
        key: "Dog",
        display: "Dog",
        styles: { flex: "0 0 10%" }
      },
      {
        key: "Cat",
        display: "Cat",
        styles: { flex: "0 0 10%" }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem by using the "value" property of the package:

```
{
        key: "DogCat",
        display: "Animals",
        styles: { flex: "0 0 25%" },
        value: (animal: AnimalDTO) => animal.Dog + ", " + animal.Cat
      }
```

This is going to give me exactly the result i was looking for.

Thanks Oscar for your answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const result = columns.map(elt => elt.key).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```